Smart Codeinsight in Delphi 12.2
I'm trying to setup Smart Codeinsight in Delphi 12.2 but when ever I'm calling it I just got "Not Found" as an answer.
Example:
{//************ Find Bugs ***************
Not Found
}

I've tried both Gemini and Chat GBT
This is my Gemini settings

And chatGBT

Have anyone got this feature working?

Isn't it "GPT"?

File a bug report

A bug report is 100% waste of time

I have been playing with Ollama, Gemini and Claude for a week or so now.
My Settings that work for me are as shown below, but remember for Gemini and Claude you will need to get an API key form their respective sites.  Please also note that the so called Free API does not seem to work with Claude and informs you that you have insufficient funds.
I am also assuming for Ollama, that you have installed using the default settings in the setup installer, loaded and downloaded your chosen Model and read the appropriate docs for using Ollama.  I chose llama3.2:1b for testing purposes, there are lots of other models to experiment with.  Please also note that Ollama with run pretty slowly in codeInsight unless you have a beefy GPU with lots of memory and a pretty beefy PC with lots of RAM and fast processor.



I hope that this is of some help to you, I will post again when I have experimented with ChatGPT.  Just as an afterthought, I have experienced odd results with Ollama not producing any output when asked to Debug Code or Optimize Code - this seems to relate to the size of the snippet you ask it to work with ...  Maybe there is a limit ;)

While your settings differ from the suggested ones in the docs, you can try with the official ones first unless you know what you are doing.
After adding some credit to my OpenAI account (and waiting a bit to give some time to promote that through their system) I was able to get some decent answers using the gpt-4o-mini model.

You are using a wrong Base URL for Gemini, the correct one is this at the time:
"https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta"

For Gemini AI I have seen also issues until I changed the Base URL as following:
https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models


Now, it is working well
